# How to download multiple HTML files while logged in on particular site?

Tags: r, automation, web-crawler

I am collecting data to my Master thesis using R package. I have list of links to pages of some auctions on auction portal (its structure is similar to eBay). The script is downloading pages (using list of links) as HTML files and then extracting data from HTML code.

The problem is, that the site which I am crawling provides additional information about auction when logged in. When I am logged out, the link to particular auction shows only basic data, but when I am logged in as some user (registration is free), it shows extended version. The R package can’t enter this portal, log in and then download pages form link, it just doesn’t have such a function. It will always download basic version of this page.

So my question is: are there any tool, which can take list of links (I have around 500 of them) as an input, and download 500 HTML files as an output, but do it as I am logged in this particular page. Maybe some plugin/extension to some browser? I need just some idea where to search, some clue is there some tool that can work the way I have described above.

Would be grateful for any ideas

Kamil